# Android AsyncTask onPostExecute accessing GUI element gives Null Pointer

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm doing an `AsyncTask` web request in Android. The web request code works and returns variables because I can output them to log no worries and see everything I need to see.

I must be misunderstanding `AsyncTask`, I thought that in the `onPostExecute` method we have access to the GUI, but I keep getting null pointers when I try to run `findViewById.`

```
TextView textView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputView);
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.w("CleverMining", "Posting results..." + result);
    textView.setText(result);
}
```

Layout XML here - **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/updateStats" android:text="@string/update_stats"></Button>

<TextView android:id="@+id/outputView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="@string/empty"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

So the log can see the correct output ezpz, but when I'm looking up the Text-view I get null pointers, implying probably out of scope or something. Pls to assist?

**How can I access a Text-view in the main activity from an onPostExecute method from an AsyncTask?**

UPDATE: LOGCAT OUTPUT AT 
http://pastebin.com/ST7r9eAW

UPDATE 2: 
Creating a class level Text-view then instantiating it in onCreate() gives me the same null pointer error.

Comment: for analyzing the NPE we will need the _full_ stacktrace of your logcat

Comment: the method setContentView() is undefined for asyncTask().  I assume to get this to compile, you have it as an innerclass.  What is your outter class?

Comment: But why are you set your layout in **onPostExecute()** method. Put it on **onCreate()** method.

Comment: check whether layout of your activity contains that view

Comment: You must need to call setContentView() on oncreate() method.

Comment: @user3126670 post you full code

Comment: I love when the question is bad and there's little or no source code…

Comment: is your layout named, R.layout.activity_main?

Comment: @AtulOHolic yeah it is

Comment: BY the information you have provide things look ok and it should run. Can you clear your project and re-run it. Also is there any piece of data which is relevant and you haven't posted yet?

Comment: @AtulOHolic I cleared the project then it worked fine. Many thanks!!

Comment: Thank God. :) Great. Have fun. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any initializaton should be done inside the onCreate() method of your Activity. So please move,

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputView);
```

to your onCreate method. And only call

```
textView.setText(result);
```

in the postExecute() method. Also ensure your textView is a class level variable to access it outside your onCreate().

Comment: Are you sure that both the layout R.layout.activity_main and R.id.outputView are present? Can you post your layout xml as well? Also , Just noticed the out put, Posting results...                            If you see that result is not being printed. Check if result has a value and add a null check before calling setText()

Comment: The result is being printed to the log fine. I updated the main question with my layout. Thanks!

Comment: is your layout named, R.layout.activity_main? Clear your project and then run.

Answer (score 1):

If you have moved your code to onCreate() then just use this in ***onPostExecute()*** method

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         if(!result.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
         textView.setText(result);

         }
    }
 });
```

Also check that your ***TextView*** id is same which is in your layout xml file.

Comment: I get the same null pointer on looking up the textView in onCreate(). It definitely exists and has the correct name, I can write to it from other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your activity context to the asynctask class. setContentView works for the Activity class not the class implementing the asynctask.

If your Activity class is called MainActivity, then you can replace the line setContentView

with MainActivity.this.setContentView()

Do the same for findViewById function as well.

Answer (score 0):

a few month ago i have this problem too. i'm not sure but i think this work!

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
Log.w("CleverMining", "Posting results..." + result);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
     TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputView);
             textView.setText(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); gives me null pointer now, what is going on...

Comment: Post your AsyncTask class with the activity